# Is there any difference between Integer and Int32 in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, integer, int32

In VB.NET, is there any difference between `Integer` and `Int32`?

If yes, please explain.

Comment: @MitchWheat...Google gave me confusing answers for this. So, thought of asking over here. I know how to search.

Comment: OK, Int32 and Integer are different. Which would you recommend using in projects where there is no pre-existing standard - and why? Presumably this thought was behind @Vikram's question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Functionally, there is no difference between the types `Integer` and `System.Int32`. In VB.NET `Integer` is just an alias for the `System.Int32` type.

The identifiers `Int32` and `Integer` are not completely equal though.  `Integer` is always an alias for `System.Int32` and is understood by the compiler. `Int32` though is not special cased in the compiler and goes through normal name resolution like any other type. So it's possible for `Int32` to bind to a different type in certain cases.  This is very rare though; no one should be defining their own `Int32` type.

Here is a concrete repro which demonstrates the difference.

```
Class Int32

End Class

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim local1 As Integer = Nothing
        Dim local2 As Int32 = Nothing
        local1 = local2 ' Error!!! 
    End Sub
End Module
```

In this case `local1` and `local2` are actually different types, because `Int32` binds to the user defined type over `System.Int32`.

Comment: @JaredPar, Thanks for explanation and thanks a lot for not putting some comment like "your google broken?" or something. :)

Comment: @MitchWheat i googled the question and didn't find a suitable explanation. Most links just say "no difference" which is incorrect.  There is one answer on the msdn website which had a decent explanation but it was fairly far down in my google results

Comment: There is no difference. Your answer states "Fuctionally there is no difference between the types"

Comment: I agree with JaredPar. That was the same reason I asked the question over here. I always believe that SO is the platform I can trust...of course, one has to face some rude comments! But, I ignore for gaining knowledge.

Comment: @MitchWheat there is a difference in how the compiler interprets the names.  This is an often overlooked difference and can bite people (especially in generated code).  You see the same effect in C# with `int` and `Int32`

Comment: When was the last time you saw Int32 not equal to System.Int32?

Comment: @MitchWheat I used to work on the .Net compiler team. I've seen this bug pop up several times (in both C# and VB.Net). As I said, people run into this in generated code or in certain nested type situations.  It's not a fictional issue

Comment: That's cool. Glad I stuck around to see this answer. I'm surprised you can do that without brackets i.e. `Class [Int32]`. Thanks

Comment: @DanVerdolino that's very much related.  `Int32` isn't a keyword in Vb.Net although many believe it to be.  It's just another name that's interpreted like anything else

Comment: @Jared: you might want to have a word with one of your colleagues! : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/2912adc7-6d11-4d2d-aa8b-60ddf7c3a3e5

Comment: @Mitch that's the post I originally saw when I Googled. SO prevails.

Comment: @MitchWheat yes that answer is incorrect. Those forums are apparently closed and I cannot offer another answer. I will sent Matt an email.

Comment: Bit of a contrived example. If people are defining there own Int32 they reap what they sow.

Comment: @MitchWheat it's a contrived example to concretely demonstrate the problem. As I said, the most common way this comes up is in generated code.

Comment: So if the question was "Is there a difference between `Integer` and `System.Int32`, then the answer would be no. Generated code *should* specify the namespace to prevent this problem from ever happening.